# How to install custom mainline kernel in Ubuntu snappy core?

Tags: kernel, raspberrypi, upstream

I have cloned latest Torvalds kernel, compiled it for raspberry pi 2 model B and generated Deb packages as well. When I install them using dpkg -i *.deb the files under /boot/firmware are not updated. Could you please support me to properly install the mainline kernel on a raspberry pi 2 model B?